# Schedule k8s cron last tuesday of the month

Tags: kubernetes, cron

I want to schedule k8s cron working every last Tuesday.

When I find that method, [blog](https://blog.healthchecks.io/2022/09/schedule-cron-job-the-funky-way/) says like below

```
0 10 */100,22-28 * TUE
```

But I check that cron schedule in crontba.gru

Cron works:

next at 2023-07-25 10:00:00
then at 2023-08-01 10:00:00    <---- this is not last tuesday!!!
then at 2023-08-22 10:00:00
then at 2023-09-26 10:00:00
then at 2023-10-24 10:00:00

How can I set k8s cron schedule to every last tuesday?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to build in the check into a command rather than try to abuse cron parser idiosyncracies. I haven't tested this, but

```
0 10 * * TUE    [[ "$(date +\%m)" != "$(date -jv +7d +\%m)" ]] && /path/to/mycmd
```

should run every Tuesday, but only executes if the month would be different if it was 7 days into the future. (`%` needs to be escaped in `crontab`, otherwise `cron` interprets it as a newline.)

This also avoids hardcoding `22-28`, which may fail to catch the last Tuesday in any month except non-leap Februaries.

Comment: What makes it trickier is that the question is about kubernetes `CronJob` so a particular container may not have bash available (or any other scripting language whatsoever)